# Getting siunitx to use text numerals, but only when it isn't in a table with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, siunitx, oldstylenums, newcomputermodern

What I want: `S` column type in tables to use tabular/lining figures. `\SI`, `\num`, `\SIrange`, etc all to use old-style/proportional numbers.

I recently asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574637/7880) about getting `siunitx` to work with old-style numerals. At the time I had the issue that all `siunitx` numbers were lining figures.

I've now moved to using `fontspec`/`lualatex`/`newcomputermodern` and have the reverse issue: Everything is proportional old-style figures, even inside tables, which I want to be tabular/lining.

`siunitx`'s `detect-all` setting is no longer doing anything, which means I can't use the previous answer.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures+{Numbers=OldStyle}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-all=false}
\string\sisetup{detect-all=false}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1 cm}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\string\sisetup{detect-all=true}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: This shows that math environments are lining figures, text are old style, and \si and S columns ignore both settings and are old style]

Comment: You appear to not have carried over `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}` from my previous answer to your new setup. Was this deliberate?

Comment: @Mico It was not, I likely missed that when testing and thus gave up and asked the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to getting `siunitx`'s macros `\SI` and `\num` and the `S` column type to work you want them to is to execute `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}`, an instruction which you provided in your [query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574637/5001) a few weeks ago but left off from the code in your new query.

The following code produces the exact same desired output -- oldstyle numerals produced by `\num` and `\SI` but not by the `S` column type -- under pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTEX. (Lining numerals are hightlighted in yellow. I use `Latin Modern` rather than the `newcomputermodern` package since I'm not familiar with the latter.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex} % for \ifpdftex macro
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{cfr-lm} % text fonts
  % (use default math font, i.e., CM Math)
\else
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % loads 'fontspec' automatically
  \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers=OldStyle]
  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % optional
\fi

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators} % <-- very important

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%% redefine \SI and \num -- carefully
\LetLtxMacro\origSI\SI
\LetLtxMacro\orignum\num
\renewcommand\SI[3][mode=text]{\origSI[#1]{#2}{#3}}
\renewcommand\num[2][mode=text]{\orignum[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
1234567890     & Text   \\
$1234567890$   & Math   \\[1ex]
\SI{1234567890}{\meter}     & \string\SI     \\
\origSI{1234567890}{\meter} & \string\origSI \\[1ex]
\num{1234567}               & \string\num    \\
\orignum{1234567}           & \string\orignum\\[1ex]
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=1.3] @{}}
    l & {S} \\
    \hline
    1.2345 &   1.2345  \\
    1.1111 &   1.1111  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

### New Answer

You can set `\SI` and `\begin{tabular}{S}` to use a different font with the option `text-rm=`.  Here is a MWE that sets both up to use fixed-width, old-style numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setsansfont{NewComputerModernSansBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmonofont{NewComputerModernMonoBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
%\setmathrm{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]
\newfontface\tablefont{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers={OldStyle,Tabular}]

\usepackage[text-rm=\tablefont, detect-all=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern tabular old-style]

And here is a new tabular environment that redefines the font `siunitx` uses, locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setsansfont{NewComputerModernSansBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmonofont{NewComputerModernMonoBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
%\setmathrm{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]
\newfontface\tablefont{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]

\usepackage[detect-all=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse} % Included by default in recent versions of LaTeX.

\NewDocumentEnvironment{SItabular}{o m}%
  {\sisetup{detect-all=true, text-rm=\tablefont}\begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx
\bigskip

\begin{SItabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{SItabular}

\bigskip
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

This avoids redefining existing commands.

### Original Answer

One solution is to set your `\mathrm` font to a version of the text font with `Numbers={Lining,Tabular}`, and tell `siunitx` to use the font `[math-rm]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[math-rm]{siunitx}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setsansfont{NewComputerModernSansBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmonofont{NewComputerModernMonoBook}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathrm{NewComputerModernBook}[Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-all=false}
\string\sisetup{detect-all=false}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1 cm}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\string\sisetup{detect-all=true}

\noindent 1234567890 Text \\
\(1234567890\) Math \\
\SI{1234567890}{\angstrom} siunitx

\begin{tabular}{Sl}
    1.234(5678) &   12345678901234567890\\
    1.111(1111) &   11111111111111111111  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the `\SI` command and the `S` column of the first table, with `detect-all=false`, display lining tabular numbers.

Another is to use the `\tablenums` command from `siunitx`. Another is to use the font `[text-tt]`.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this answer doesn't actually accomplish what I asked. This has the S column type and \SI using the same type of numbers (lining or old style) and what I asked was for \SI to use old style while S uses lining.

Comment: @Canageek Okay. I wrote two new answers that should be closer to what you wanted.

Comment: @Canageek Sorry for the mistake!